# Http 415 Unsupported Media type error with JSON

Tags: java, json, http-status-code-415

I am calling a REST service with a JSON request and it responds with a `HTTP 415 "Unsupported Media Type"` error.

The request content type is set to `("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf8")`.

It works fine if I don't include a JSON object in the request. I am using the `google-gson-2.2.4` library for JSON.

I tried using a couple of different libraries but it made no difference.

Can anybody please help me to resolve this?

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

    JsonObject requestJson = new JsonObject();
    String url = "xxx";

    //method call for generating json

    requestJson = generateJSON();
    URL myurl = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);

    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf8");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    con.setRequestProperty("Method", "POST");
    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    os.write(requestJson.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
    os.close();


    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
    int HttpResult =con.getResponseCode();
    if(HttpResult ==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));  

        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
        sb.append(line + "\n");  
        }
         br.close(); 
         System.out.println(""+sb.toString());  

    }else{
        System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());  
    }  

}
public static JsonObject generateJSON () throws MalformedURLException

{
   String s = "http://www.example.com";
        s.replaceAll("/", "\\/");
    JsonObject reqparam=new JsonObject();
    reqparam.addProperty("type", "arl");
    reqparam.addProperty("action", "remove");
    reqparam.addProperty("domain", "staging");
    reqparam.addProperty("objects", s);
    return reqparam;

}
}
```

The value of `requestJson.toString()` is :

`{"type":"arl","action":"remove","domain":"staging","objects":"http://www.example.com"}`

Comment: Please update your question with the value of `requestJson.toString()`

Comment: Value of requestJson.toString is :

{"type":"arl","action":"remove","domain":"staging","objects":"http://www.abc.com"}

Comment: Have you written the server part? If you do the same request with Postman (Chrome extensions, Google it), does it work? Perhaps the server does not accept the JSON content type for some reason?

Comment: Yes I tested that using soapUI. I sent the exact same request including json and got successful response from the server.

Comment: @joscarsson, since 14 Mar 2017, Postman chrome extension is deprecated. They moved to the native app. Here is their blog post: [http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/03/14/going-native/](http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/03/14/going-native/)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Not sure about the reason, but removing `charset=utf8` from  `con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf8")` resolved the issue.

Comment: It's probably a bug in the ReST service.  They're probably not expected the `charset` to be set in the Content-Type.  My guess is that they're checking if the string `"application/json; charset=utf-8" == "application/json"`.  That being said, JSON must be utf-8 so it's perfectly valid to leave out the charset.

Comment: Because `charset=utf8` is not a valid character set designation.  The correct version would be `charset=utf-8`.  The dash is important.  The list of valid character set designations is managed by IANA RFC2879: http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml

Comment: Wasted a whole lot of time trying different things and then tried removing the charset=utf8 and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: In some implementations, like Dart http, `charset=UTF-8` is the only way to use it.

Comment: Which file contains this so I can remove it?

Answer (score 114):

Add `Content-Type`: `application/json` and `Accept`: `application/json`

Comment: If you using **Postman** for testing, try to add this part to the **Headers**: Content-Type: application/json

Answer (score 22):

If you are making jquery ajax request, dont forget to add

```
contentType:'application/json'
```

Answer (score 16):

This is because `charset=utf8` should be without a space after `application/json`. That will work fine. Use it like `application/json;charset=utf-8`

Comment: This is incorrect; spaces are allowed and should be ignored; see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046 .

Answer (score 13):

HttpVerb needs its headers as a dictionary of key-value pairs

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'charset': 'utf-8'}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you get this in React RSAA middleware or similar,
Add the headers:

```
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(model),
```

Answer (score 8):

Incase if you are giving a post request through `Postman` then make sure you have choosed these 2 options

**1.** **JSON (application/json)** should be choosed
[image]

**2. Content-Type** - application/json

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `AJAX` `jQuery` Request this is a must to apply. If not it will throw you `415` Error.

```
dataType: "json",
contentType:'application/json'
```

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue and the solution was to remove

```
'mode': 'no-cors'
```

and adding the hostname as an allowed origin at backend server.
Setting mode to 'no-cors' will always take "Content-Type" as "text/plain".
For more info, visit [info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode)

Comment: but if I remove this line from `fetchBaseQuery` I will get `cors issue`

Answer (score 2):

Add the HTTP header manager and add in it your API's header names and values.
e.g. Content-type, Accept, etc. That will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with Postman. Adding  `Content-Type: application/json` to the headers solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Some times Charset Metada breaks the json while sending in the request. Better, not use charset=utf8 in the request type.

Comment: utf8 just isn't a valid character set.  Look at the spec: http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by updating the `Request` class that my Controller receives.

I **removed** the following class level annotation from my `Request` class on my server side. After that my client **didn't get 415 error.**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
@XmlRootElement
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case: on the body params I set the param to text type instead of JSON
I thought its all the same .:)

Answer (score 0):

I was sending "delete" rest request and it failed with 415. I saw what content-type my server uses to hit the api. In my case, It was "application/json" instead of "application/json; charset=utf8".

So ask from your api developer And in the meantime try sending request with content-type= "application/json" only.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My problem was complicated object for serialization. One attribute of my object was `Map<Object1, List<Object2>>`. 
I changed this attribute like `List<Object3>` where `Object3` contains `Object1` and `Object2` and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is way too late to help the OP with his problem, but to all of us who is just encountering this problem, 
I had solved this issue by removing the constructor with parameters of my Class which was meant to hold the json data.

Answer (score 0):

Add MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter manually in configuration solved the problem for me :

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class RestConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters) {
        messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(messageConverters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason can be not adding "annotation-driven" in your dispatcher servlet xml file. and also it may be due to not adding  as application/json in the headers

Answer (score 0):

> The 415 (Unsupported Media Type) status code indicates that the
> origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload
> is in a format not supported by this method on the target resource.
> The format problem might be due to the request's indicated
> Content-Type or Content-Encoding, or as a result of inspecting the
> data directly.
> [DOC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.13)

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue when working REST service with a JSON request and it responds with a HTTP 415 "Unsupported Media Type" error.
These lines of codes will help you to resolve the issue.

> headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "accept": "*/*" },

After that, you should write code to encode the JSON body.
For an example,

> body: jsonEncode({"username": username, "password": password})

Answer (score 0):

In the Postman, in the Headers, you might insert the folows Keys and values
Key = Content_Type    VALUE application/json
Key = Accept          VALUE application/json

It is must work!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue even after adding correct “Content-Type” & “content-type” headers. The issue resolved when I added “x-version” header with value as “4”.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `'Content-Type': '*/*'` and `'accept': '*/*'` in headers resolve this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your request might need a empty body {} even if you have no body data.

```
body: {}
```