# angular with resteasy - Mediatype unsupported error

Tags: angularjs, resteasy

I am trying to submit a form to the backend rest service from angularjs controller and getting unsupported media type even i submit the header with content type.

Error :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415
>   (Unsupported Media Type)

Angular controller :

```
    $scope.formData = {
        'name':'test',
        'email':'test@test.com'
    };

    function get(restUrl, formData) {
    function success(result) {

        return result.data;
    }

    function error(err) {
        return err.data;
    }
    return $http({
        url: restUrl,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
        method: "GET",
        timeout: 200000,
        params: formData
    }).then(success, error);
}
```

Java form class,

```
public class SearchForm {

    private String name;
    private String email;

    public SearchForm() {
        super();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Rest controller,

```
@Named
@Singleton
@Path("/api/v1/")
public class SearchController {

  @GET
    @Path("/getAll")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<ResultDto> getReconLogs(@Context final HttpServletRequest request, final SearchForm searchForm) {
}
}
```

Is there anything required in the Angular controller or any annotation in the form class?

Thanks

Comment: Server API issue - `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type)` but what help will you get by this? `function success(result) {

        return result.data;
    }

    function error(err) {
        return err.data;
    }` It is a promise trigger function. Where are you catching it or are there more promises?

Comment: Gary, Error handling on the client side is different. I am trying to know, Why the request is not fulfilled by the server and it returns 415 error.

Answer (score 0):

Server API or definition issue. Your client side is ok but not `function success(result) { return result.data; } function error(err) { return err.data; }` promises are not used like this. You cannot return result.data from success or error. You have to assign or capture it or do some manipulations.

Try this to set definitions:

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

[Http 415 Unsupported Media type error with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566433/http-415-unsupported-media-type-error-with-json)