# 415 Unsupported Media Type in Restkit response

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit

I'm trying to call a rest web service in an iOS application using Restkit but I get this error : 
restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:210 response.body=415 Unsupported Media Type

## 415 Unsupported Media Type

I puted this line in my code to set the content type as application/json:

```
objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
```

and this is my request shown in the console

```
request.headers={
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Accept-Language" = "en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, zh-Hans;q=0.7, zh-Hant;q=0.6, ja;q=0.5";
    Authorization = "Basic U1lTQURNSU46aHVsNTU4ODg1OA==";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    "User-Agent" = "iosProj/1 (iPad Simulator; iOS 8.3; Scale/2.00)";
}
```

Then I found that the problem could be caused by "charset=utf-8" as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566433/http-415-unsupported-media-type-error-with-json/).
My question is how to remove "charset=utf-8" in Restkit

Comment: I guess you'll need to have RestKit create the `NSURLRequest` and then set the new content type header explicitly

Comment: Thank you @Wain, it work : 
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Wain comment I solved the problem by creating the request and setting the content type header :

```
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];    
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor
                                            responseDescriptorWithMapping: [LoginResponse getResponseMapping]
                                            method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                            pathPattern:nil
                                            keyPath:@"OutputParameters"
                                            statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone. This happened recently to me and I was missing Content-Type as well. However you can easily add that to RKObjectManager as:

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:YOUR_BASE_URL]];
[manager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
```