# Spring REST Jackson - StringBuilder Is Not Binding With JSON

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson, spring-rest

I am using Spring MVC RESTful webservices & Client is RestTemplate. Everything is working fine by using jackson to bind json to bean but when i add StringBuilder property in bean then client getting below exception

**org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://":Server returned HTTP response code: 415 for URL: http:// nested exception is java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 415 for URL: http://**

**Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 415 for URL: http://**

> **Please note :** In my project, Bean have over 5000 properties with nested, complex and all types of objects are having in that single
>   bean.  Really i struggled to found that problem causing because of
>   having StringBuilder property in one nested object but it is different
>   from above exception. So i don't know how others are finding these kind
>   of problems since exception is different from actual problem.
>
> **Request headers are :** Headers : {Accept=[application/json, application/*+json], Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]. I
>   am getting same request header on both client as well as server.
>
> **Request body :** {"id":"1","name":"Shas","sb":null}

If anybody have solution then please share it.

Client Side:

```
final String uri = "http://localhost:8282/WS/rest/add";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory()));
List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
interceptors.add(new LoggingRequestInterceptor());
restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
Person person = new Person();
person.setId("1");
person.setName("Siva");
restTemplate.postForObject(uri, person, Person.class);
```

Server Side :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Person addPerson(@RequestBody final Person person) {
        try {
            if (person != null) {
                System.out.println("Person ID : "+person.getId());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Request Obj is null at ws controller");
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return person;
}
```

Person.java

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String id = null;
    private String name = null;
    private StringBuilder sb = null;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public StringBuilder getSb() {
        return sb;
    }
    public void setSb(StringBuilder sb) {
        this.sb = sb;
    }
    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

}
```

Exception full trace :

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://":Server returned HTTP response code: 415 for URL: http://; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 415 for URL: http://
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:580)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:330)
    at com.xxx.xxx(XXX.java:2782)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 415 for URL: http://
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1624)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getBody(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:81)
    at org.springframework.http.client.BufferingClientHttpResponseWrapper.getBody(BufferingClientHttpResponseWrapper.java:69)
    at com.xxx.LoggingRequestInterceptor.traceResponse(LoggingRequestInterceptor.java:41)
    at com.xxx.LoggingRequestInterceptor.intercept(LoggingRequestInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$RequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:84)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:69)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:569)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Do you need `sb` on the client, because you can ignore its conversation to json with `@JsonIgnore`

Comment: Current i am doing by @JsonIgnore. But i need a solution for this.

Comment: can you attach the full trace of the exception on your java machine?

Comment: @ Amer i have added please check it.

Comment: Post your incoming JSON as well. The error seems to indicate it might be corrupt (or not JSON at all)

Comment: @ jwenting, Please see my update.

Comment: @Easy2DownVoteHard2Ans : provide the full client code & how you are building the server url in vaiable `uri`. there is some issue in the value of uri.

Comment: @ Pratik, Please see my updated client code. The problem is because of StringBuilder, if i remove StringBuilder property then everything is working fine.

Comment: You can try that http://stackoverflow.com/a/22643964/4144381

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers of the API you're trying to hit?

Comment: @ Durlabh, i have updated with request headers. Please check it.