# In Jmeter I am trying to send a post rest api request containing json in body and getting unsupported media 415

Tags: json, rest, api, jmeter

I am using Jmeter in order to send a request:

```
POST http://192.168.56.100:9080/agent/v1/target

POST data:
{  
   "eventsServers":"192.168.56.100:9999",
   "targetType":"kafka"
}
```

I am getting the following error:
{"code":415,"message":"HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type"}
when I am running it from another rest api tool I am not getting this error

what could be the problem ?

Comment: Did you set the content-type header? `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566433/http-415-unsupported-media-type-error-with-json

Comment: Yeah that was the problem I did not add 'Header-Manager'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Http 415 Unsupported Media type error with JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566433/http-415-unsupported-media-type-error-with-json)

Answer (score 8):

Just add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to your Test Plan and configure it to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [application/json](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type)

[image: JMeter Header Manager Content Type]

Check out [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) article for more information on setting up a web service load test with JMeter

Answer (score 2):

Add **HTTP Header Manager** to your thread group

[image: Add Content-Type in Name and application/json in value]

Add Content-Type in Name and application/json in value