# Java Spring - 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, json, spring

Here is my Controller:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public User someName(@RequestBody  User user){
        System.out.println(user.toString());
        return user;
    }

}
```

User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
    private String secondname;
    private String email;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(Integer id, String name, String secondname, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.secondname = secondname;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public User(String name, String secondname, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.secondname = secondname;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "secondname")
    public String getSecondname() {
        return secondname;
    }

    public void setSecondname(String secondname) {
        this.secondname = secondname;
    }

    @Column(name = "email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder().append(this.name).append(", ").append(this.secondname).append(", ")
                .append(this.email).toString();
    }
}
```

And my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>pl</groupId>
  <artifactId>javalab</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>javalab Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
       <java-version>1.7</java-version>
   </properties>

   <repositories>
       <!-- Repository for ORACLE JDBC Driver -->
       <repository>
           <id>codelds</id>
           <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
       </repository>
   </repositories>

   <dependencies>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>junit</groupId>
           <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
           <version>3.8.1</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>

       <!-- Servlet API -->
       <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
           <version>3.1.0</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>

       <!-- Jstl for jsp page -->
       <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
           <version>1.2</version>
       </dependency>


       <!-- JSP API -->
       <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/jsp-api -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
           <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
           <version>2.2</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>

       <!-- Spring dependencies -->
       <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
           <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>

       <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
           <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>

       <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
           <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>

       <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
           <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>

       <!-- Hibernate -->
       <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
           <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
       </dependency>

       <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
           <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
       </dependency>


       <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
           <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
       </dependency>


       <!-- MySQL JDBC driver -->
       <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>mysql</groupId>
           <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
           <version>5.1.34</version>
       </dependency>

       <!-- Oracle JDBC driver -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
           <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
           <version>11.2.0.3</version>
       </dependency>

       <!-- SQLServer JDBC driver (JTDS) -->
       <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
           <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
           <version>1.3.1</version>
       </dependency>

        <!-- Mail Start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mail End -->


            <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>javalab</finalName>
    <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
               <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.2</version>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

When I want to post in in postman:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "secondname": "test",
    "email": "test@test.pl"
}
```

I have an error: `415 Unsupported Media type`
More precisely I have: `The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.`

In postman I choose `raw` and `JSON (application/json)`. As headers I have written: `Content-Type` as key and `application/json` as value.

Somebody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Http 415 Unsupported Media type error with JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566433/http-415-unsupported-media-type-error-with-json)

Comment: can you share your spring configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the chrome's inspect to see the HTTP header of your postman's request.Check whether the content-Type is corrent.

Answer (score 0):

This is so common in spring. Make your entity serializable.