# Failure in updating Atlassian Jira label using REST API

Tags: curl, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to update a Jira Label using postman and curl but both of the methods are failing with different error message.

> curl -D- -u userName -X PUT --data "{ "update": { "labels": [ {"add" :
>   "new_label"} ] } }" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
>   https://jira-internal.net/rest/api/2/issue/APP-12345

Formated input json

```
{  
   "update":{  
      "labels":[  
         {  
            "add":"new_label"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, no-transform
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 20 Jul 2017 00:32:30 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=7D2377622EC43724B9EF35E0CA7F6E20; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: atlassian.xsrf.token=BEF9-GHD2-UUG5-5KAQ|dc2355ac9338b0cc1396b1fd68a8268785ac6589|lin; Path=/; Secure
X-AREQUESTID: 32x6573810x14
X-ASEN: SEN-2063834
X-ASESSIONID: 1ak5dqh
X-AUSERNAME: userName
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Seraph-LoginReason: OK
transfer-encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

{"errorMessages":["Unexpected character ('u' (code 117)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@6e73489c; line: 1, column: 4]"]}%
```

With postman I'm getting following error:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.55 - Error report</title>
 <style>
 <!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}-->
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type</h1>
 <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
 <p>
 <b>type</b> Status report
 </p>
 <p>
 <b>message</b>
 <u>Unsupported Media Type</u>
 </p>
 <p>
 <b>description</b>
 <u>The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.</u>
 </p>
 <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
 <h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.55</h3>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution which worked with curl:

```
 curl -u userName -X PUT --data "{ \"update\": { \"labels\": [ {\"add\" : \"test_Label\"} ] } }" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://url/rest/api/2/issue/APP-1234
```

OR

```
curl -u userName -X PUT --data '{ "update": { "labels": [ {"add" : "test_label"} ] } }' -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://url/rest/api/2/issue/APP-1234
```

Notice the "'" around the JSON data.

For Postman:

1. Headers Tab: Content-Type : application/json
2. Make sure to add the json data as raw to the body and select JSON type.

[image: Body tab]

Comment: This worked. The Jira API documentation is not clear enough. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your call adding `"""` instead of `"`

```
curl -D- -u userName -X PUT --data "{"""update""": {"""labels""": [ {"""add""": """new_label"""}]}}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://jira-internal.net/rest/api/2/issue/APP-12345
```

For Postman look this answer: [Http 415 Unsupported Media type error with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566433/http-415-unsupported-media-type-error-with-json)

Comment: Thanks @Roberto but this does not work. I figure out the correct escape characters.