# Unable to update labels in a JIRA issue via JIRA REST API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am sending the below PUT request to JIRA and unable to update the ticket. I am receiving 200 Http Status code with the ticket details JSON in response. However, this doesn't include the updated labels.

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://jiraserverurl/rest/api/2/issue/APP-1' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXX' \
  --data-raw '{
     "update": {
       "labels": [
          {
           "add" : "newlabel"
          }
       ]
     }
   }'
```

I referred to this article [Failure in updating Atlassian Jira label using REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45203740/failure-in-updating-atlassian-jira-label-using-rest-api) and did everything in a same way. However, it still doesn't update.

Unfortunately, I am receiving 200 Success response. Therefore, no clue of why it is not working!!

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there; just change `--data-raw` to `--data` (or `-d`) and try body in same line:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://jiraserverurl/rest/api/2/issue/APP-1' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXX' \
  --data '{ "update": { "labels": [{ "add" : "newlabel"}]}}'
```

Comment: I am using Postman. I got it as --data-raw in Postman cURL. Is there any other way to make it work in Postman?