# Unable to POST data to server in android using WebServices API

Tags: android, mysql, api, post

I want to POST data to server but i get

> Volley: [1726] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 415 for http://192.158.20.43:8080/Api/employee/create" error.

```
public class RegisterTextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText emailBox, passwordBox,firstName,lastName;
    Button registerButton;
    TextView loginLink;
    String URL = "http://192.158.20.43:8080/Api/employee/create";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_text);

        firstName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstname);
        lastName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lastname);
        emailBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailBox);
        passwordBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordBox);
        registerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
        loginLink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.loginLink);

        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        if(s.equals("true")){
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterTextActivity.this, "Registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterTextActivity.this, "Can't Register", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                },new Response.ErrorListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        volleyError.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterTextActivity.this, "Some error occurred -> "+volleyError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    public String getBodyContentType() {
                        return "application/json;charset=utf-8";
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        parameters.put("firstname",firstName.getText().toString().trim());
                        parameters.put("lastname",lastName.getText().toString().trim());
                        parameters.put("email", emailBox.getText().toString().trim());
                        parameters.put("phone", passwordBox.getText().toString().trim());
                        return parameters;
                    }

                };

                RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterTextActivity.this);
               /
                rQueue.add(request);
            }
        });

        loginLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterTextActivity.this, LoginTestActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

API work fine in POSTMAN but not work properly here.

Comment: is your internet connection active and permission mention in manifest ?

Comment: Yes i put the INTERNET permission in manifest and inernet connection is active.

Comment: yes link is properly working in POSTMAN

Comment: I think this is the local host link and you need to connect to the same server.

Comment: This other question might have the answer you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566433/http-415-unsupported-media-type-error-with-json

Comment: Sir i'm connected with same link. i can access all data in my testing device.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your Content-Type

> application/json;charset=utf-8

to

> application/json

Comment: Volley: [2974] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for "http://192.158.20.43:8080/Api/employee/create";                                  W/System.err: com.android.volley.ServerError                                                 W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:179)
 W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)

Comment: Your body content seems to be: 

application/x-www-form-urlencoded 

try change your Content-Type to '   application/x-www-form-urlencoded   '

if not work try change your request into json request