# Uploading file to API or web services using jMeter

Tags: jmeter

- **File details are provided in file upload configuration and use multipart/from data for Post is checked though unable to upload file in jmeter for API**
  -as the UI is not available for webservice I am unable to judge name parameter value in file configuration, can someone please help to proceed upload scenario without providing Parameter name in jMeter.

I tried to perform File uplaod through jmeter using POST menthod, and getting server side error as below:

**Web Service Error
javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type**
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.SpecExceptions.toHttpException(SpecExceptions.java:117) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.toHttpException(ExceptionUtils.java:157) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.findTargetMethod(JAXRSUtils.java:526) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:177) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:77) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307) [cxf-core-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]

Comment: **Gone through the solution provided on** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566433/http-415-unsupported-media-type-error-with-json                                                 ---- but jMeter sending "content type : MIME type" mentioned in file upload configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HTTP Status Code 415](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415) means that the server doesn't recognise or accept the [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header you're sending.

Add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) as a child of the relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and configure it to send the relevant `Content-Type` header which would be [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type) for REST API or `application/soap+xml` for [SOAP](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_soap.asp)