# 415 Unsupported Media type when doing POST

Tags: java, jpa, post, jakarta-ee, quarkus

I have these two classes `Item` and `Drink`. Where `Drink` extends `Item`. Both are PanacheEntities and only consists a few basic fields. Code samples of this part (I left the getters and setters out of it):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_items")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Item extends PanacheEntity {
   @Column(nullable = false)
   private String title;
   @Column
   private String description;
   @Column(nullable = false)
   private float price;
   @Column
   private LocalDateTime lastUpdatedDate;
   @Column(nullable = false)
   private String lastUpdatedUser;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_drinks")
public class Drink extends Item {
    @Column
    private int volume;

    @Column
    private boolean containsAlcohol;

    @Column
    private float alcoholPercentage;
}
```

I am still in the phase of creating some basic CRUD operations. So I have this POST operation in the controller which I want to test via Postman, but it returns a 415 error code.
This is the controller function:

```
@POST
@Path("/drinks")
public Response addDrink(Drink drink, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    Long drinkId = drinkRepository.persistDrink(drink);
    UriBuilder builder = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(Long.toString(drinkId));
    Log.info("drink persist");
    return Response.created(builder.build()).build();
}
```

And this is the repository function that gets called:

```
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
public Long persistDrink(Drink drink) {
    Drink.persist(drink);
    Log.info(String.valueOf(drink.id));
    return drink.id;
}
```

I do know that there should be a domain layer in between for best practices, but that will be fixed after this problem.

This is the body I enter in the Postman call:

```
{
    "title": "Cola",
    "description": "Refreshing soda",
    "price": 2.5,
    "lastUpdatedDate": "2023-06-05T10:00:00",
    "lastUpdatedUser": "John Doe",
    "volume": 500,
    "containsAlcohol": false,
    "alcoholPercentage": 0.0
}
```

Where is the problem? I already tried to add `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`, but that does not work either.

Comment: What headers are you using in Postman? What is the return data format you are expecting and returning?

Comment: @Chris Headers are the default ones. I think the most important one is this one: `Content-type: application/json`. I would expect that the repository returns a `Long` (the ID of the new Drink) and the controller returns a `Response` as you can see on the code examples

Comment: Have you gone through the solutions in this thread?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566433/http-415-unsupported-media-type-error-with-json

Comment: @AltafAlamAnsari None of them worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that worked for me:

Commenting the `quarkus-resteasy-reactive` dependency in the `pom.xml` and adding this code in the `pom.xml` instead.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Do not forget to reload/rebuild your application