VBA xmlhttp not working on ACCESS VBA Code but same working in POSTMAN
I have below VBA Code in MS Access which is giving me Authorization error(403 - Forbidden) but when I try the same in POSTMAN, It is working using same data. What am I doing wrong ? Note. This is only problem with PUT method. With Get method where only TOKEN is required and CSRF Token is not needed it will working fine for VBA code. Is there any cookie from CSRF Token needs to be write ?
Public Sub AddUserToGroup(GroupID As String, UserID As String)
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Dim url As String
    Dim authToken As String
    Dim csrfToken As String
    Dim jsonBody As String
    Dim responseText As String
    Dim strCookie As String
    
    ' Initialize variables
    url = fetchUrl("groups")
    
     ' Get request headers
    Set headers = getHeaders("PUT")
 
    ' Prepare JSON body
    jsonBody = "{""schemas"": [""urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:Group""], " & _
               """id"": """ & GroupID & """, " & _
               """members"": [ { ""value"": """ & UserID & """, ""type"": ""User"" } ] }"
      
    ' Create XMLHTTP object
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
       
    ' Open HTTP request
    xmlhttp.Open "PUT", url, False
 
    'Set request headers
    xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", headers("Content-Type")
    xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "x-sap-sac-custom-auth", headers("x-sap-sac-custom-auth")
    xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "x-csrf-token", headers("x-csrf-token")
    xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", headers("Authorization")
    
    ' Send the request
    xmlhttp.Send jsonBody
    
    ' Get response
    responseText = xmlhttp.responseText
    
    ' Display response
    MsgBox "Response: " & responseText
    
    ' Cleanup
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
End Sub


getHeaders() is a function?  How is its return value created?

Yes, GetHeaders builds all headers. I figured out, that was due to  xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", headers("Authorization") statement. Not sure why it is causing issue. I do see Token being generated under this header but seems some extra char. in Authorization causing the issue. I hard coded the authorization and now I am getting "415 unsupported media type" error. I am passing  xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json" for content type but still same issue. Any suggestion ?

?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566433/http-415-unsupported-media-type-error-with-json

Compare request and response with access VBA to those via postman using Telerik fiddler and find the differences.

Debug the values of headers().

I hard coded value xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/scim+json") still same error. I know this API is taking Content-Type = application/json

I switched to CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP") and it worked for the same content-type. Wierd. Thanks for all of your help
