# android retrofit2 could not add header (415 error code)

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp, skyscanner

I'm trying to access ticket data via skyscanner api and pass it to my view, but I cannot accomplish that, because I get **415 error code** I'm using retrofit2 and adding header programmatically. My interface looks like this:

```
public interface GetFlightDetails {

@POST("apiservices/pricing/v1.0/")
Call<TicketData> getFlightList(@Query("apiKey") String apiKey,
                                @Query("country") String country,
                                @Query("currency") String currency,
                                @Query("locale") String locale,
                                @Query("originPlace") String originPlace,
                                @Query("destinationPlace") String destinationPlace,
                                @Query("outboundPartialDate")String outboundPartialDate,
                                @Query("inboundPartialDate") String inboundPartialDate,
                                @Query("locationschema") String locationschema,
                                @Query("cabinclass") String cabinclass,
                                @Query("adults") int adults,
                                @Query("children") int children,
                                @Query("infants") int infants,
                                @Query("groupPricing") boolean groupPricing) ;
}
```

and in my activity, when I'm ready to make a request I have the following code:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
            .create();


    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    //adding logging
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
    httpClient.interceptors().add(logging);
    //headers
    httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();

            //adding header info
            Request request = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .method(original.method(), original.body())
                    .build();

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build();

    GetFlightDetails api = retrofit.create(GetFlightDetails.class);

    Call<TicketData> mresponse = api
            .getFlightList(API_KEY, country, currency, locale, from, to,
                    departDate.substring(0,10), returnDate.substring(0,10),
                    locationSchema, cabinClass, adult, children, infants, false);

    mresponse.enqueue(new Callback<TicketData>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<TicketData> call, Response <TicketData> response) {

            if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                Log.d("UnSuccess", response.raw().toString());
                return;
            }
            else {
                progress.cancel(); //cancel progress dialog
                Log.d("Success", response.raw().toString());
                TicketData ticketData = response.body();

                RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ticketData);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<TicketData> call, Throwable t){
            progress.setMessage("Retrofit Error Occured");
        }
    });
```

and in my log file I see the following error:

```
com.example.ex D/OkHttp: --> POST http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0/?apiKey=xxxxxxxx&country=US&currency=USD&locale=en-us&originPlace=SFO&destinationPlace=LAX&outboundPartialDate=2016-10-24&inboundPartialDate=2016-10-31&locationschema=iata&cabinclass=Economy&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&groupPricing=false http/1.1 (0-byte body)
com.example.ex D/OkHttp: <-- 415 Unsupported Media Type http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0/?apiKey=xxxxxxxx&country=US&currency=USD&locale=en-us&originPlace=SFO&destinationPlace=LAX&outboundPartialDate=2016-10-24&inboundPartialDate=2016-10-31&locationschema=iata&cabinclass=Economy&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&groupPricing=false (403ms, 0-byte body)
com.example.ex D/UnSuccess: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=415, message=Unsupported Media Type, url=http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0/?apiKey=xxxxxxxx&country=US&currency=USD&locale=en-us&originPlace=SFO&destinationPlace=LAX&outboundPartialDate=2016-10-24&inboundPartialDate=2016-10-31&locationschema=iata&cabinclass=Economy&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&groupPricing=false}
```

I'm not sure why it occurs, because I've tried to add headers in my interface.

Skyscanner docs [reference 1](http://business.skyscanner.net/portal/en-GB/Documentation/FlightsLivePricingList) and [reference 2](https://github.com/Skyscanner/api-documentation/tree/master/live_flights_pricing)

Thanks!

Comment: Refer this link to get answer [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717209/android-retrofit2-could-not-add-header-415-error-code/57818389#57818389)

Answer (score 4):

Please refer same type of example : Check your parameter type which filed is query string and which field is @Field and etc.,

```java
public static final String TRAVEL_API = "http://business.skyscanner.net/";

public interface TravelApiInterface {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @Headers("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
    @POST("/apiservices/pricing/v1.0/")

    void getTravelApi(
        @Field("country") String country,
        @Field("currency") String currency,
        @Field("locale") String locale,
        @Field("locationSchema") String locationSchema,
        @Field("apikey") String apikey,
        @Field("grouppricing") String grouppricing,
        @Field("originplace") String originplace,
        @Field("destinationplace") String destinationplace,
        @Field("outbounddate") String outbounddate,
        @Field("inbounddate") String inbounddate,
        @Field("adults") int adults,
        @Field("children") int children,
        @Field("infants") int infants,
        @Field("cabinclass") String cabinclass, Callback<Object> response);
}
```

TravelApiInterface currencyRequestInterfaceService;

```
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(Url.TRAVEL_API)
            .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                @Override
                public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                    request.addQueryParam(getString(R.string.api_key_title), getString(R.string.api_key_value));
                }
            })
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();

    currencyRequestInterfaceService = adapter.create(TravelApiInterface.class);
```

====================
sample request

```
requestConversion("UK", "GBP", "en-GB", "iata", "xxxxxxxx","on", "EDI", "LHR", 
    "2016-10-04", "2016-10-11", 1, 0, 0, "Economy", new Callback<Object>() {

                @Override
                public void success(Object o, Response response) {

                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                }
});
```

In strings.xml

```
<string name="api_key_title">apikey</string>
<string name="api_key_value">xxxxxxx</string>
```

Comment: I'm using retrofit 2 and code you posted an answer that is based on retrofit 1, could you please modify it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We need to give Content-Type for this problem and need to pass as model class

```
@Headers("Content-Type:application/json")
@POST("saveAddressByFE")
Call<ChangeAddressModel> updateAddress(@Body AddressModel addressModel );
```

Retrofit response

```
 private void getUpdateAddress(AddressModel addressModel) {
    UploadService service = APIClient.getClient(CommonSettings.MY_RECORDING_SERVER_URL).create(UploadService.class);
    Call<ChangeAddressModel> call = service.updateAddress(addressModel);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ChangeAddressModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ChangeAddressModel> call, Response<ChangeAddressModel> response) {
            if (response.body().getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                Toast.makeText(InsuranceAgentDetailsActivity.this, "Submitted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ChangeAddressModel> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(InsuranceAgentDetailsActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


}
```

Model class

```
public class ChangeAddressModel {
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

}

the data we are going to send  model class(AddressModel addressModel)

```
public class AddressModel {
private String addressType,address,custId;

public AddressModel(String addressType, String address, String custId) {
    this.addressType = addressType;
    this.address = address;
    this.custId = custId;
}

public String getAddressType() {
    return addressType;
}

public void setAddressType(String addressType) {
    this.addressType = addressType;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getCustId() {
    return custId;
}

public void setCustId(String custId) {
    this.custId = custId;
}
```

}